# How to reuse form fields in components and update values in React

Tags: reactjs

Im trying to update form fields in an **Update form** that is reusing **Create** component.
However, the current behavior is im unable to edit the text fields and also is only capturing a single change only

Example i want to update these values with:  2nd Project dddd, Hello rrrr
[image]

AFTER EDITING: It only captures the first letter
[image]

**Create.js:**

```
const Create = ({
  formTitle = "Create a new project",
  values = {},
  handleBtn = "Add project",
  onTitleChange,
  onBodyChange,
}) => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [body, setBody] = useState("");
  const [isPending, setIsPending] = useState(false);
  const [submitMsg, setSubmitMsg] = useState("");
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  onTitleChange = (e) => {
    setTitle(e.target.value);
  };

  onBodyChange = (e) => {
    setBody(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    /* prevent refreshing */
    e.preventDefault();
    const project = { title, body, date }; /* project object */
    setIsPending(true);
    setSubmitMsg("Project added!\nRedirecting back to home page");
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/projects", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(project),
    }).then(() => {
      console.log("New project added ");
      setIsPending(false);
      setTimeout(() => navigate("/"), 1000);
    });
  };
  return (
    <div className="create">
      <h2 className="project-title">{formTitle}</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label className="title">
          <b>Title:</b>
        </label>
        <textarea
          type="text"
          required
          value={values.title}
          onChange={onTitleChange}
        ></textarea>
        <label>
          <b>Project:</b>
        </label>
        <textarea
          type="text"
          required
          value={values.body}
          onChange={onBodyChange}
        ></textarea>
        <br />
        {!isPending && <button className="add-project">{handleBtn}</button>}
        {isPending && <button disabled>Adding project...</button>}
        <div className="success">{submitMsg} </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Create;
```

**Update.js:**

```
const Update = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    id: id,
    title: "",
    body: "",
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:5000/projects/" + id)
      .then((res) => {
        setValues((values) => ({
          ...values,
          title: res.data.title,
          body: res.data.body,
        }));
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, [id, values]);

  const handleTitleChange = (e) => {
    setValues({ ...values, title: e.target.value });
  };

  const handleBodyChange = (e) => {
    setValues({ ...values, body: e.target.value });
  };

  return (
    <div className="update">
      <Create
        formTitle="Update Project"
        values={values}
        onTitleChange={handleTitleChange}
        onBodyChange={handleBodyChange}
        handleBtn="Update project"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Update;
```